# Graceful recovery of length prefixed binary streams in c#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

So I'm looking into writing binary "messages" to disk. Currently I'm opting to prefix length onto the beginning of the "message", so I can easily say read x bytes from stream and then deserialize it etc.

This is a specific case where I'd like to be able to continue to read past messages that fail to parse and recover any messages that existed further in the sequence.

In researching ways to delimit binary data by byte sequences, it seems like its generally not advised (as there is always a possibility that sequence COULD occur naturally in the stream), but with length header prefix, I'm not sure how you could ever recover reading records from the stream if you weren't just reading until you hit some magic sequence and then reading the next length etc.

I'm looking at specifically c# and protobuf, but it seems like it's a more general topic.

Any suggestions with how I could reliably delimit with a byte sequence, or recover from a corrupt packet where length doesnt match what was written to disk?

Comment: If you're anticipating "the length might be wrong" don't you need to equivalently anticipate "the delimiter might be wrong" and get into the same sort of problem? Note that you could have a malformed message but still have the correct length of it - so in that case you can still skip past it. Personally I'd advise trusting the length and going from there. You could always include a hash for the length-prefixed data as well, so you can *detect* that something absolutely fatal has happened, even if you couldn't move past it.

Comment: I mean those are valid points, but its not so much a problem with determining whether the bytes that are there are invalid, its finding the beginning of the next length header etc. I also dont anticipate this happening but we have seen disk streaming, incomplete write, then picked up streaming appending to the same file. Can never access the newly appended content because bad packet of data, and no way to know where to pick up with the next header

Answer (score 0):

All audio formats are using frame sync (your magic sequence) + length header + CRC check, so audio decoders can recover from broken streams. You should do the same, before the protobuf deserializer.

MP3 https://checkmate.gissen.nl/headers.php

Ogg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg_page

Comment: Yeah I think the magic sequence is the key... if I could tell this is the start of a header, or this is the start of a record, I could easily accommodate the rest. I'm just curious what that magic sequence is in these audio codecs.

Ogg apparently uses `OggS`. Interesting. I assume that's less risk given the nature of ogg codecs, but I think something like that could easily be doable.